# MySQL backups of information_schema?

Tags: mysql

When performing routine MySQL backups (using `mysqldump`), should I be including `information_schema`?  Isn't it just meta information?

I've seen multiple suggestions to ignore the `mysql` and `performance_schema` databases. (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3456885/11760)

Should I also omit `information_schema`?  Would you ever want to restore it?

Comment: If you continue reading the comments below the accepted answer to the link you included, the questions are already answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it was pointed out by [yoonix](https://serverfault.com/users/143703/yoonix) in a comment to my question, the answer to my question was actually given in the comment to the question I highlighted in my original question.

> "Don't bother to drop information_schema. It is in fact just a bunch
>   of read-only views, not tables. And there are no files associated with
>   the them. There isn't even a directory for the database. The
>   informations_schema is using the memory db-engine and is dropped and
>   regenerated upon stop/restart of mysqld. See
>   [dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-schema.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-schema.html)."
>   - [John P](https://stackoverflow.com/users/94629/john-p)